# Input Missmatch Exception with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have problem with this peace of code:

```
String name;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

name = scan.next();
```

When i enter string with space in it( for example "Alfonso Alfonsov" ) this throws Missmatch exception. When i enter it without space ( "AlfonsoAlfonsov" ) everything is OK...
Any idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: Sure?? I think it should work fine.

Comment: can you post exception stacktrace?

Comment: I think something is wrong with "Scanner"... whathever.. i solve the problem with DataInputStream...

Comment: The problem is solved with BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))

Answer (score 0):

name = scan.nextLine();

This should work